# Trigger.io What version of android/iOs is supported?

Tags: mobile, trigger.io, versions

I looked through trigger.io website and haven't found an answer for this question.
Can anybody help me?

Also, is it planned to support windows phones by Forge framework?

Answer (score 0):

The following Mobile Platforms are supported (see this [blog](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2014/12/19/another-splendid-year-at-trigger-io/) post for more detail):

- iOS 8
- Android 5.0

Trigger.io does not currently support Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

- **Android:** 2.x - 5.0 (API levels 5 - 21)
- **iOS:** 5 to 8

Source: [Trigger.io requirements config doc](https://trigger.io/docs/current/tools/config.html#requirements) and [Trigger.io release notes](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html)

From my point of view, Windows Phone support is nowhere to be seen in the near future. Disclaimer: I'm a long term customer.